Failed to open page
I am not able to start the development server in my MacBook Safari browser. This problem did not existed before but recently after upgrading the Mac OS I am facing the problem.
I expect that I start the development server to begin coding in WebStorm.
I went through this article but it did not solve the problem.


Probably related to Mac app security (not a Mac user, just a though). Anyway -- see if https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/articles/SUPPORT-A-564 will be of any help (it's not about the same, but maybe it will give you some clues).

Hi, just a side note: using images for code or errors causes a lot of problems. Use images only to illustrate graphical issues. Please read Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?.  Thank you
